# moodle.sty does not insert tikz graphics into xml output file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, circuitikz, xml, moodle

I want to generate quizzes to be imported to the Moodle platform. The quizzes include tikz drawings.

I use the moodle 2021/01/04 57334 v0.8 package with TeX Live 2020/W32TeX on Windows 10. When I run pdflatex the .pdf and .xml files are generated without any error message, but the base64 encoded image is not included in the xml output file. All the commands required by moodle.sty are installed (ghostscript, imagemagick, and optipng). All tikz output files (..-tikztemp-1.pdf, ..-tikztemp-1.png, ..-tikztemp-1, ..-tikztemp-1.aux, ..-tikztemp-1.dpth, ..-tikztemp-1.log, ..-tikztemp-1.md5) are generated in the directory of the input .tex file. The file ..-tikztemp-1 contains the encoded image that should be inserted into the xml file. Manually copying the contents of ..-tikztemp-1 into the xml file results in an xml file that can be imported to the Moodle platform successfully.

Here is an example file.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[section,tikz]{moodle}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,esint}

\usepackage[american,siunitx,smartlabels,EFvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quiz}[points=10,penalty=0.5]{Trial}
        \begin{shortanswer}[points=30]{EC-P001}
            For the electric circuit below, obtain the equivalent resistance at the terminals a-b.
            \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw
                    (0,3) node[left]{a} to[R, l^=\SI{25}{\ohm}, o-] ++(3,0)
                    to[R, l^=\SI{10}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
                    to[R, l^=\SI{20}{\ohm}] ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0)
                    to[R, l^=\SI{15}{\ohm}] ++(0,-3)
                    to[short, -o] (0,0) node[left]{b}
                    (3,3) to[short, *-] ++(0,1.5)
                    to[R, l^=\SI{30}{\ohm}] ++(6,0)
                    to[short, -*] ++(0,-1.5)
                    (6,3) to[R, l^=\SI{5}{\ohm}, *-*] ++(0,-3)
                    ;\end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
            \item 36.25 Ohm
        \end{shortanswer}
    \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

I run `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode`. The relevant output from pdflatex is

```
...
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "file-tikztemp-1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{file}\input{file}"' ========
runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname
 "file-tikztemp-1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{file}\input{file}")...executed.

\openout5 = `file.auxlock'.

<file-tikztemp-1.pdf, id=29, 331.72932pt x 158.65575pt>
File: file-tikztemp-1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use file-tikztemp-1.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: file-tikztemp-1.pdf  used on input line 97.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 331.72852pt x 158.65535pt.
moodle.sty: Converting picture 'file-tikztemp-1.pdf' to PNG...
runsystem(gswin64c.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=file-tikztemp-1.png -r150 file-tikztemp-1.pdf)...executed.

moodle.sty: Optimizing 'file-tikztemp-1.png'...
runsystem("C:\Portable Program Files\OptiPNG\optipng.exe" file-tikztemp-1.png)...executed.

moodle.sty: Converting 'file-tikztemp-1.png' to base64...
runsystem(certutil -encode "file-tikztemp-1.png" tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64 > "file-tikztemp-1" && del tmp.b64")...executed.

moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'file-tikztemp-1.enc'...
moodle.sty: base64 data saved.
\openout5 = `file.auxlock'.
...
```

But in the xml output file the decoded base64 image is not included, I only get the following where the image should be inserted:

```
... <IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64,"> ...
```

Thanks

Comment: It compiles correctly for me on a Linux system, so it must be something system-related. Try to remove the `-syntex=1 -interaction-nonstopmode` and see if it stops on some error.

Comment: The same result - no error. The LaTeX run compiles correctly and the pdf output is okay. The only issue is that the encoded picture is not inserted into the xml output.
I noticed that the output file with the encoded picture does not have a file extension ( file-tikztemp-1). Looking through the moodle.sty file, it looks like moodle.sty looks for the encoded picture in ---.enc, which is not being created. That could explain that moodle.sty inserts a non-existing (= empty) file. Is that possible?

Comment: Hmmm... yes. it is very strange that line: `findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64 > "file-tikztemp-1` it should have a `.enc` at the end. Let me see...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it refers to a bug already fixed in the development release

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following: copy the file `moodle.sty` of your distribution in your current directory, together with your test file.

Edit that file and, around line 3330, you'll find:

```latex
\def\cmdline{\baselxiv\otherspace -encode "#1#2"\otherspace tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64 > "#1" && del tmp.b64"}%
```

Try to change this to:

```
\def\cmdline{\baselxiv\otherspace -encode "#1#2"\otherspace tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64 > "#1.enc" && del tmp.b64"}%
```

(Notice the added `.enc`) and try again.

This was already reported as a bug: https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/-/issues/81

Comment: Version 0.9 of `moodle`, solving the issue of the missing `.enc`, will be released in the coming days. @Kirsten Let us know if @Rmano 's solution does not help.

Comment: @Rmano's solution fixed the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: @mgk ok, it seems all right

Comment: OK. Sorry for this bug.

Comment: @mgk "Chi non fa non falla" it's a saying in Italian --- the only way to have no bug is not to make any software. You're doing great!

Comment: Grazie @Rmano. I'm just kindly blaming myself because this one was actually silly.